# Is there a way to reverse looking up and down?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

Hopefully self-explanatory, but I would find it much more natural to use right stick up to look down and right stick down to look up. Is there a way to achieve this in Skyrim on PS3?

I couldn't see anything obvious in the controls settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

menu-system-settings-invert y easy fix

Comment: OK, so it's a PS3 system setting rather than a game one. That would explain it! Thanks... (will accept answer as soon as I'm allowed to).

Comment: no the menu in game, where the quests, general stats, and settings screen is